# I want to split into `String and `int` arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I have text data and I want to split into `String` and `int` arrays Java

```
String text = "one1two20three300four4000";
```

Desired output:

```
String str[] = "one","two","three","four";

int num[] = 1,20,300,4000;
```

Comment: Why `JavaScript` is tagged ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the following document to learn how to write good, answerable questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @MosamMehta - Not exactly. He cannot split it *directly*. He will have to do some preprocessing to prevent empty array values

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This one will work for you in Java :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "one1two20three300four4000";
    String arr1[] = text.replaceFirst("^\\d+", "").split("\\d+");
    String arr2[] = text.replaceFirst("^\\D+", "").split("\\D+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // parse each value as an in using Streams (preferably) or a loop.
}
```

O/P :

> [one, two, three, four] 
>  [1, 20, 300, 4000]

PS : In java 8 Use `int[] arr2Int = Arrays.stream(arr2).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();` to convert your String array to int array.